# RunAsDate app for Windows Mobile 5?

Tags: windows-mobile, runas

There is a handy app called RunaAsDate for Windows O/S, but I couldn't find such an app for Windows Mobile 5.  I need it to extend the trial version of an app called SprintDB Pro 4, because it seems that SprintDB is out of business and no longer selling licenses.  I would prefer not to have to constantly change the PDA's clock settings every time I use the app.  If anybody has any insight, please let me know.
Thank you in advance, Nathaniel

Comment: Can you simply change the date on the device? I am not familiar with [RunAsDate](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/run_as_date.html).

Comment: yes I am currently changing the date, but that isn't ideal for professional use.